# Change delimiter in csv file - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, io, delimiter

I have a csv file in google colab (python) called 'student-mat.csv'
when I print it, it looks like this:
  school;sex;age;address;famsize;Pstatus;Medu;Fedu;Mjob;Fjob;reason;guardian;traveltime;studytime;failures;schoolsup;famsup;paid;activities;nursery;higher;internet;romantic;famrel;freetime;goout;Dalc;Walc;health;absences;G1;G2;G3

The delimiter is wrong and I do not know how to change it, as instead of writing simple code like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('student-mat.csv')
```

I have to write this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['student-mat.csv',delimiter=';'].decode('utf-8')))
print(df.head())
```

This is because I uploaded the file differently. And when I type that code it is incorrect because the delimiter is in the wrong spot. It gives a simple `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You should explain what doesn't work about your current attempt. By the way, you should avoid reassigning `csv.writer` as you are doing. Next time you try to use the function, you will get an error. Looks like you're already seeing this error...

Comment: Per MarianD's answer... I was going to say it sounds like you need to indicate the delimiter when reading in the file... :)

Comment: @hoop_coop, have you tried using `sep` parameter of `pd.read_csv` and specify your delimiter character? Have a look at more options [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @JatinBansal Thanks for the suggestion, but i ended up finding an answer that was way more simple (ive only just started in python, so my bad). thanks for taking the time to answer though, hope you have a good day/night :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you complicated yourself your life? Simply use

```
df = pd.read_csv('student-mat.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

See [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv).

Comment: I did so and got the following error: EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file. Could this be because i am using google colab and imported the file using: from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

Comment: Show 2-3 first lines of your .csv file, or count yourself the number of semicolons in them.

Comment: If you are using colab then it must be storing the file in sample_data folder. do `ls` and check where your file is. and then do `!cat path/<file_name>`

Comment: @MarianD i have edited the question, you can see there

Comment: @Pygirl, usually it would be but i imported using this code {from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload().}

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter needs to be placed here:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['student-mat.csv'].decode('utf-8')), delimiter=';')

print(df.head())
```

This then returns it in a pandas DataFrame.